Magento 2.4.7 P3 fresh installation admin configuration Js error on console
I set up a simple Magento 2.4.7 p3 site on server, and set it up. Noticed that admin section gets stuck on configuration page. Checked console, and it shows multiple Js files 404 could not find.
Initially I thought this might be because I hadn't purchased any domain and ssl. But after I did those, the issue is still there. No tabs are opening on admin configuration.

I deployed static content for admin section specifically, but didn't resolve the problem. Tried with Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Issue is same all across browsers.

https://www.thecoachsmb.com/error-while-installing-magento2/ Try this.
